# Refresh fragment with changes to textfields

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have a fragment in an activity with a couple of TextEdit fields. 
I have a method which displays the fragment, either with standard EditText values, or with values fetched from a database.

But when the fragment is previously shown, the fragment won't update it self with the new values in the textfields when shown for a second time.

From what I've gathered, this is because Android is recycling views, so I've tried to invalidate the fragment when displayed for the second time, in order to refresh it, but this doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

In activity (UPDATED)

```
public void showEditBirthdayFragment(boolean showExisting, int listIndex) {

    if(showExisting) {
        Birthday birthday = getBirthdayArray().get(listIndex);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        String date = format.format(birthday.getBirthdate());
        int day = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2));
        int month = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3,5));
        int year = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(6));

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", birthday.getName());
        bundle.putString("phone", birthday.getPhonenumber() + "");
        bundle.putInt("day", day);
        bundle.putInt("month", month);
        bundle.putInt("year", year);

        editBirthdayFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.mainActivity, editBirthdayFragment, "editBirthdayFragment");
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

In fragment:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    editTextName = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextPhone = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
    datePicker = (DatePicker) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    savedInstanceState = getArguments();

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        editTextName.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("name"));
        editTextPhone.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("phone"));
        datePicker.updateDate(savedInstanceState.getInt("year"), savedInstanceState.getInt("month"), savedInstanceState.getInt("day"));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your whole code because this doesn't give idea how the values are setting

Comment: you should use `setArguments` method to send values to `editBirthdayFragment`

Comment: @MehulJoisar
Updated my code now. Still no luck.

Comment: @dex Posted more, and updated my code now

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Needed to get and set the values in the fragments `onResume()` method instead of its `onActivityCreated()` method.